# Does $E[X] = E[X|X < a]P\{X < a\} + E[X|X ≥ a]P\{X ≥ a\}$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

> **Question.** Does $E[X] = E[X|X < a]P\{X < a\} + E[X|X ≥ a]P\{X ≥ a\}$?

I would like some hint on how to start this, and mostly if this affirmation is true, whichever hint would help me a lot, I don't know how to start.

Comment: yes, its true. Just use the definition of conditional expectation to show it

Comment: This is the [Law of Total Probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability). You need to give more [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). You should also state the question in the question, not only in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The partitioning of the outcome space and the linearity of expectation, along with the following definition, leads to that result.

By definition, $\mathsf E(X\,\mathbf 1_{\{X\in A\}}) = \mathsf E(X\mid X\in A)~\mathsf P\{X\in A\}$

Where $\mathbf 1_{\{X\in A\}}$ is the indicator function for the event $\{X\in A\}$. It equals $1$ when the event holds, and $0$ where it does not.

So $$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) &=\mathsf E(X~\mathbf 1_{\{X <a\}\cup\{X\geq a\}}) \\[1ex]&= \mathsf E(X~(\mathbf 1_{\{X< a\}}+\mathbf 1_{\{X\geq a\}}))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(X~\mathbf 1_{\{X<a\}})+\mathsf E(X~\mathbf 1_{\{X\geq a\}})\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(X\mid X<a)~\mathsf P\{X<a\}+\mathsf E(X\mid X\geq a)~\mathsf P\{X\geq a\}\end{align}$$